# Finding it hard to use a href template tag in Django

Tags: django, url, tags, view, django-templates

I seem to have some difficulty trying to use a href template tag. Here is what I want to do.

I have an edit order form at

```
(r'^orders/edit/(?P<order_no>\d+)/$', views.edit_order),
```

I want a link that could take me to this html template items.html
I will name this url

```
(r'^orders/edit/add_items/(?P<client_id>)/$', views.add_items),
```

And my views looks like this.

```
@login_required
def add_items(request, client_id = 0):
    client = None
    items = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        items = client.storageitem_set.all()
    except:
        return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
    return render_to_response('items.html', {'items':items, 'client':client}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

@login_required
def return_clients(request):
    clients = models.Client.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('clients.html', {'clients':clients}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

In my edit order form template I have this.

```
<a href="{% url tiptop.views.add_items client.pk %}">Add Item</a>
```

Now when I restart my server, I click on the link and I go for some reason to this page.

/orders/edit/add_items//

I think maybe I need a 'for' loop, but for some reason when I tried to do this, the href disappeared.

**EDIT:** I have put in views.edit_order

```
client = models.Client.objects.all()
```

and in edit_order template

```
{% for c in client %}
        <a href="{% url tiptop.views.add_items client.pk %}">{{c.name}}</a><br />
{% endfor %}
```

While running server again, this displays all clients names but like before all clients links goes again to 
/orders/edit/add_items//

Comment: Is your link in clients.html or items.html?

Comment: Link is in the edit order form (edit_order.html), where it should have a link to this template (items.html)

Comment: What is the view that renders `edit_order.html` though? Does it have a `client` variable in the context?

Comment: I have looked at the view that render the edit order. There is NO client variable.

Comment: If there's no client variable, how would your edit order form display a link to {% url tiptop.views.add_items client.pk %} ? In this case, client doesn't exist.

Comment: Problem is if I define client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id) in views.edit_order, there is a problem with this because I wil always get the error edit_order() takes exactly 3 non-keyword arguments (2 given).

Comment: "...`(?P<client_id>)`..." Notice anything missing?  A "\d+", perhaps?  Your {% url %} call isn't recognizing the url because it can't match the int you're passing it with the nothingness that is your client_id match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer myself.

```
def edit_order(request, order_no):
# some code 
    name = order.contact.client


<a href="{% url tiptop.views.client_items name.pk %}">Add Item</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `client` library at you case is undefined (I assume that HTML you have shown is located in clients.html)

Try this:

```
{% for client in clients %}
    <a href="{% url tiptop.views.add_items client.pk %}">Add Item</a><br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This was what I did before. But what happen is when I ran the server and went to a (r'^orders/edit/(?P<order_no>\d+)/ page, The href link does not appear.